# Meteor template helper mongo call crashing app

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a Meteor app that has become very unresponsive now that I am trying to use Templates and Template helpers more. I basically have two large collections in MongoDB say `collection1` with 1531589 documents and `collection2` with 1517397 documents. For each collection, the documents within it adhere to a single schema, i.e. collection1 has it's own schema, and collection2 has it's own schema. Both schemas have only a few properties (~5). In my Meteor code I have taken the following approach

```js
Col1 = new Mongo.Collection('collection1');
Col2 = new Mongo.Collection('collection2');
```

In **publications.js**

```js
Meteor.publish('collection1', function() {
    if (Roles.userIsInRole(this.userId, 'admin')) {
        return Col1.find({"ID": "12345"});
    } else {
        this.stop();
        return;
    }
});

Meteor.publish('collection2', function() {
    if (Roles.userIsInRole(this.userId, 'admin')) {
        return Col2.find({"ID": "12345"});
    } else {
        this.stop();
        return;
    }
});
```

In **subscriptions.js**

```js
Meteor.subscribe('collection1');
Meteor.subscribe('collection2');
```

I then have templates that should display data from each collection by means of template helpers, so in essence

```html
<template name="superInfo">
  {{#each latestInfo}}
    <p>{{latestInfo.prop1}}</p>
    <p>{{latestInfo.prop2}}</p>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

with a template helper

```js
Template.superInfo.helpers({
    latestInfo: function() {
        return Col1.find({"ID": "12345"}, {
            sort: {Date: -1},
            limit: 1
        });
    }
});
```

I know the fault probably lies with how I am querying/publishing/subscribing and I have read posts like [this](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/understanding-meteor-publications-and-subscriptions/) but I still can't figure out the most efficient way of doing this. Another issue might be how I have configured Mongo locally? I have made sure that there are indexes on each collection for the `ID` field, but that hasn't helped. Whenever I start my app and browser to the page using these templates it becomes totally unresponsive.

I put a few `console.logs` in the template helpers and noticed they were getting called quite a lot so that also might be an issue. Any suggestions as to how best to address these issues would be really appreciated.

Comment: Did you add the index in your mongo db or in your meteor app (using _ensureIndex())?

Comment: Directly in the mongo shell

Comment: Here is a [blogpost](http://joshowens.me/how-to-optimize-your-mongo-database-for-meteor-js/) that shows how to optimize your mongodb. Maybe it helps.

Comment: I read that and that's why I then made sure to have indexes

Comment: How many documents match that query? Thousands? Also you should `return this.ready()` in the `else` case of your publishers, especially if you are using `waitOn`.

Comment: Yeah about 2000 match